# Как изменить URL ссылку для бота телеграмм Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, url, telegram, бот

Пытаюсь добавить эту ссылку в url-кнопку телеграмм бота. Не получается.

```
viber://add?number=79005002020
```

Выдает ошибку [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: unsupported URL protocol"}']"

Читала документацию, пыталась сделать, но никак, не хватает опыта.

Вставить url сюда нужно. Буду очень рада, если поможете, объясните

```
button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пример текста', url=url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка переводится как *"Плохой запрос: неподдерживаемый URL протокол"*.

Дело в том, что Telegram поддерживает ссылки только по протоколам `HTTP` и `tg`, а у Вас `viber`. То есть Вы не можете добавить ссылку такого вида.

---

Описание параметра `url` у [`InlineKeyboardButton`](https://core.telegram.org./bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton):

> *Optional*. HTTP or tg:// url to be opened when button is pressed

Comment: То есть даже никак не видоизменить ссылку?

Comment: @ПолинаОрлова Viber не имеет web-версии, поэтому у него нет `http`-ссылок. Видимо, никак. Но можно воспользоваться отдельным сервером, который будет отвечать на `HTTP`-запрос перенаправлением на глубокую ссылку.